# Buffer and value filter

Tags: android, filter, bluetooth, buffer, spp

I'm running trough a curious bug where I receive bad values from a serial connection. I created a post earlier but no one have responded yet. 
[other problem] : [Bluetooth SPP (serial) glitchs (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538575/bluetooth-spp-serial-glitchs-android)

Because I would like to finish this project soon I think I will have to implement a "patch" that will filter all the values.  If the new value is around +/- 15% to my previous value I will keep it and if it exceed this cutoff range I will discard it. Here is the code where I receive the values :

```
hBluetooth = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case RECEIVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // If we receive a message
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String stringIncome = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);             // Create string from byte array
            stringBuilder.append(stringIncome);                                             
            int endOfLineIndex = stringBuilder.indexOf("\r\n");                 // Determine the end-of-line
            Log.e(TAG, "Line"+endOfLineIndex);
            if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // If we are at the end-of-line we parsed all the data that was sent
                rmsgBluetooth = stringBuilder.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);     // The string is extracted in a string object rmsgBluetooth
                stringBuilder.setLength(0);
```

Could some one help me to implement a filter that will output the retained value in a string ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

```
    sensorReading = Float.parseFloat(rmsgBluetooth);
                        if(Math.abs(sensorReadingOld - sensorReading)<10 || sensorReadingOld == 0 ){
                            sensorReadingOld = sensorReading;       

                        }
                        else {
                            sensorReading = sensorReadingOld;
                        }
```